# What causes 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' when using com.sun.mail in JavaMailSender?

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

i got exeption when i try use JavaMailSender for send text with smtp google.

[There is dependencies in my projcet:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfrFe.jpg)

[Config EmailSender:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD0SH.jpg)

Thre is implementation of message sending logic:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmailSenderService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendEmail(String toEmail,
                          String Subject,
                          String body)
    {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("maksymchukmaxym@gmail.com");
        message.setTo(toEmail);
        message.setText(body);
        message.setSubject(Subject);

        mailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail send Successfully");
    }
```

And fragment Controller where used service sending email:

```
    @Autowired
    EmailSenderService emailService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/createuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createJobSeeker(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("email") String email,
                                  @RequestParam("password") String password, @RequestParam("type") String type, Model model)
      throws IOException, SQLException {

        int randomPIN = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
        String[] splited = name.split("\\s+");

        try {

            if (type.equals("seeker")) {

                JobSeeker j = new JobSeeker();
                j.setFirstName(splited[0]);
                j.setLastName(splited[1]);
                j.setPassword(password);
                j.setEmailId(email);
                j.setVerificationCode(randomPIN);
                j.setVerified(false);

                JobSeeker j1 = jobSeekerDao.createJobSeeker(j);

                String verificationUrl = "http://localhost:8080/register/verify?userId=" + j1.getJobseekerId() + "&pin="
                        + randomPIN + "&type=seeker";


               // emailService.sendSimpleMessage(email, "Verification Pin", verificationUrl);
                emailService.sendEmail(email, "Verification Pin", verificationUrl);
               // emailService.sendSimpleMessage(email, "Verification Pin", verificationUrl);
                model.addAttribute("name", j1.getFirstName());
                return "codesent";
```

**Exeption is: ervlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil.getBooleanSessionProperty(javax.mail.Session, java.lang.String, boolean)'] with root cause**
[How can i fix that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSB8F.jpg)

itried connect newer version of javax.mail but it doesn't help

Comment: *NoSuchMethodError* indicates incompatible libraries